# OpenCV: shape detection

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have .jpg file of different shapes. I am trying to detect the shape of each figure and print it besides it. I am using the below code to create and draw contours.

```
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for con in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(con, 0.01*cv2.arcLength(con, True), True)
    cv2.drawContours(img, [approx], 0, (0,0,0), 5)

if len(approx) == 4:
        cv2.putText(img, "Quadrilateral", (x,y), font, 1, (0))
```

Now that I have figured out `cv2.approxPolyDp()` joins the contour points and create a boundary definite to the shape, How do I determine the exact shape, i.e whether it is square or rectangle? As in the above code if 
`len(approx) == 4`

This is the Image:

[image: e-p]

Comment: Think of the definition of the square and the rectangle. For square all of the sides should have the same length (with some eps) and two consequent sides should have angle of 90 degrees (in clockwise or counter-clockwise order). Create similiar logic for the restangle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [aspect ratio](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_properties/py_contour_properties.html#aspect-ratio) to distinguish between a square and a rectangle. By observation, a square has equal length and width whereas a rectangle has one side longer. This same logic can be applied to identify a circle vs oval. Here's the results:

[image]

```
import cv2

def detect_shape(c):
    shape = ""
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * peri, True)

    # Triangle
    if len(approx) == 3:
        shape = "triangle"

    # Square or rectangle
    elif len(approx) == 4:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
        ar = w / float(h)

        # A square will have an aspect ratio that is approximately
        # equal to one, otherwise, the shape is a rectangle
        shape = "square" if ar >= 0.95 and ar <= 1.05 else "rectangle"

    # Pentagon
    elif len(approx) == 5:
        shape = "pentagon"

    # Otherwise assume as circle or oval
    else:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
        ar = w / float(h)
        shape = "circle" if ar >= 0.95 and ar <= 1.05 else "oval"

    return shape

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,51,7)

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    shape = detect_shape(c)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.putText(image, shape, (x, y - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (36,255,12), 2)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```